# How to avoid 'MissingManifestResourceException' after chaning Assembly Name?

Tags: c#, wpf

I encountered this exception after changing the assembly name (the default namespace remains the same).

> An exception of type
>   'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for
>   the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "NQR
>   GUI.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked
>   into assembly "NQR GUI" at compile time, or that all the satellite
>   assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

After hours of searching the web and trying different solutions, I still haven't found a way to resolve this problem. I'm really frustrated about this, because this is the only project where I encountered this problem. I would be very grateful if someone will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I was using the localization solution presented [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249369/Advanced-WPF-Localization?fid=1649916&df=90&mpp=50&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Tight&fr=101#xx0xx). After changing the Assembly Name I had to specifically write it in the xaml code:

```
LocalizationScope.ResourceManager="{ResourceManager AssemblyName='New assembly name', BaseName='Default Namespace.Properties.Resources'}"
```

And to get rid of the "assembly not found" IntelliSense error, I had to restart Visual Studio. I hope this answer will eventually help someone who will encounter this problem.